# How do I parse Json with an invalid character for a field name? e.g. { "file/folder": "/Shared/Salesforce/asdf.txt" } with Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I received the following JSON from a webservice. How do I parse the following JSON in Netwtonsoft?

```
{ "file/folder": "/Shared/Salesforce/asdf.txt" } 
   ^^^^^^^^^^
   ^^^^^^^^^^
   ^^^^^^^^^^---that is my problem
```

Note that the field name has a forward slash, which is invalid for C# when used as a field name.  (Newtownsoft does automatic mappings between JSON names and C# fields)

The code I have is

```
       JsonSerializerSettings set = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        List<UserAudit> usrs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAudit>>(statusResult );

        foreach (var item in usrs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.username + " " + item.ip_address);
        }
```

Note how all NewtownSoft needs is the same name for the Javascript object in C#.  It handles all the conversion.

```
 public class UserAudit
 {         

    public string username;
    public string filefolder;  // <----- HOW DO I SET THIS VARIABLE?  "file/folder" is invalid 
    public string transaction;
    public string access;
    public string time;

}
```

**Additional research**

I looked at the overload for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAudit>>(statusResult);` and didn't see a direct way to rename or reformat the data when it comes in.  I looked at both JsonSerializerSettings, and JsonConverters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use JSON attributes to specify the name of the property to map to the model.

```
public class UserAudit
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("file/folder")]
    public string FileFolder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("transaction")]
    public string Transaction { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("access")]
    public string Access { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

It's common with most serializers to look for attributes to define how they should serialize/deserialize.

Comment: perfect! I'll accept this in 9 minutes.  Somehow I missed the introductory course on this

Answer (score 0):

Change it from this.

```
    "/Shared/Salesforce/asdf.txt"
```

to this

```
    @"/Shared/Salesforce/asdf.txt"
```