# Json with slash in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slash

I have a little problem in picking up the data from the JSON actually can get some data, however when you have the occurrence of "/_string" the script error.

example:

## JSON

```
"results":[{
price_value_prices: 15.05
price_value_prices/_currency: "USD"
price_value_prices/_source: "$15.05" 
}];
```

## AJAX

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: $url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    data.results[$n].price_value_prices/_sources
  }
});
```

### console log output

```
_sources is not defined
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is because your JSON is invalid - all keys and values must be wrapped in quotes, eg: `"price_value_prices/_source": "$15.05"`. If you fix that you can then access the property using `data.results[$n]['price_value_prices/_sources']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse Json with an invalid character for a field name? e.g. { "file/folder": "/Shared/Salesforce/asdf.txt" } with Newtonsoft?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865260/how-do-i-parse-json-with-an-invalid-character-for-a-field-name-e-g-file-fol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, your JSON is invalid without the quotes on the left side for the field names, so change it to:

```
"results":[{
  "price_value_prices": 15.05
  "price_value_prices/_currency": "USD"
  "price_value_prices/_source": "$15.05" 
}]
```

And then access it using the `[]` operator.

```
data.results[$n]["price_value_prices/_sources"]
```

You cannot use `/` because it is another operator. If you have `/` or `.` in your field names, it is wise to use the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid in four different ways:

1. You have a property initializer outside of any object initializer.
2. Property keys must be in double quotes in JSON.
3. You must have commas between properties in an object.
4. You have a `;` at the end of it.

#2 would solve your `/` problem.

Here's a valid version:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "price_value_prices": 15.05,
        "price_value_prices/_currency": "USD",
        "price_value_prices/_source": "$15.05"
    }]
}
```

Assuming you parse that and assign the result to `obj`, you can access `price_value_prices/_currency` using brackets notation and quotes (any kind):

```
console.log(obj.results[0]["price_value_prices/_currency"]);
console.log(obj.results[0]['price_value_prices/_currency']);
```

Note the `[0]` after `results`, since it's an array with a single entry in it.